# Using DTOptionsBuilder to hide header table using Angular DataTables

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

Normally according to the documentation of Datatables I think it is necessary to give a value `false` to `fixedHeader`
`.withOption('fixedHeader', false)` but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hack using css

```css
.inventory_related thead {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>row value 1</td>
    <td>row value 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class='inventory_related'>
  <thead>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>row value 3</td>
    <td>row value 4</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```